# Understanding Django JSONField key-path queries and exhaustive sets

Tags: django, postgresql, jsonb

While looking at the Django docs on [querying JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield), I came upon a note stating:

> Due to the way in which key-path queries work, [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) and [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) are not guaranteed to produce exhaustive sets. If you want to include objects that do not have the path, add the `isnull` lookup.

Can someone give me an example of a query that would not produce an exhaustive set? I'm having a pretty hard time coming up with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ticket that resulted in the documentation that you quoted: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31894

**TL;DR:** To get the inverse of `.filter()` on a JSON key path, it is not sufficient to only use `.exclude()` with the same clause since it will only give you records where the JSON key path is present but has a different value and not records where the JSON key path is not present at all. That's why it says:

> If you want to include objects that do not have the path, add the isnull lookup.

---

If I may quote the ticket description here:

> Filtering based on a JSONField key-value pair seems to have some
> unexpected behavior when involving a key that not all records have.
> Strangely, filtering on an optional property key will not return the
> inverse result set that an exclude on the same property key will
> return.
>
> In my database, I have:
>
> - 2250 total records 49 records where jsonfieldname = {'propertykey': 'PropertyValue'}
> - 296 records where jsonfieldname has a 'propertykey' key with some other value
> - 1905 records where jsonfieldname does not have a 'propertykey' key at all
>
> The following code:
>
> ```
> q = Q(jsonfieldname__propertykey="PropertyValue")
>
> total_records = Record.objects.count()
> filtered_records = Record.objects.filter(q).count()
> excluded_records = Record.objects.exclude(q).count()
> filtered_plus_excluded_records = filtered_records + excluded_records
>
> print('Total: %d' % total_records)
> print('Filtered: %d' % filtered_records)
> print('Excluded: %d' % excluded_records)
> print('Filtered Plus Excluded: %d' % filtered_plus_excluded_records)
> ```
>
> Will output this:
>
> ```
> Total: 2250
> Filtered: 49
> Excluded: 296
> Filtered Plus Excluded: 345
> ```
>
> It is surprising that the filtered+excluded value is not equal to the total record count. It's surprising that the union of a expression plus its inverse does not equal the sum of all records. I am not aware of any other queries in Django that would return a result like this. I realize adding a check that the key exists would return a more expected results, but that doesn't stop the above from being surprising.
>
> I'm not sure what a solution would be - either a note in the documentation that this behavior should be expected, or take a look at how this same expression is applied for both the exclude() and filter() queries and see why they are not opposites.